# Why does this runtime dynamic binding fail?

Tags: c#, dynamic

Why does the following test fail?

```
[TestClass]
public class DynamicTests
{
    public class ListOfIntsTotaller
    {
        public float Total(List<int> list) { return list.Sum(); }
    }
    public static class TotalFormatter
    {
        public static string GetTotal(IEnumerable list, dynamic listTotaller)
        {
            //  Get a string representation of a sum
            return listTotaller.Total(list).ToString();
        }
    }
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestDynamic()
    {
        var list = new List<int> { 1, 3 };
        var totaller = new ListOfIntsTotaller();
        Assert.AreEqual("4", totaller.Total(list).ToString()); // passes 
        Assert.AreEqual("4", TotalFormatter.GetTotal(list, totaller)); // fails
    }
}
```

With the following error:

> `Test method MyTests.DynamicTests.TestDynamic threw exception:`
>   `Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: The best overloaded method match for
>   'MyTests.DynamicTests.ListOfIntsTotaller.Total(System.Collections.Generic.List<int>)'
>
>   has some invalid arguments`

Shouldn't the binder be smart enough to match `list` to its underlying type of `List<int>` and thus successfully bind to the `GetTotal` method?

Comment: To me, it seems to be as simple as you instructed listTotaller to be dynamically resolved at runtime, you said no such thing about list. So the error about trying to pass `IEnumerable` to a method accepting `List<int>` seems reasonable to me.

Comment: Interesting...  if I change the GetTotal method signature to be *GetTotal(dynamic list, dynamic listTotaller)*, it works.  Thanks Anthony!

Comment: @Anthony: If dynamic method calls didn't have overloads resolved at runtime, the feature would be nigh on useless. One of the motivations for this feature is making implementation of dynamically typed languages on the CLR easier. This includes freeing them from having to fake overload resolution and letting them just have the CLR take care of method calls.

Comment: @Inerdia, clearly the overload is being resolved at runtime. It can't be compile-time here, the compiler doesn't even know the type of the object the method belongs to. However, the runtime still follows the same rules the compiler would follow once the type of `listTotaller` becomes known.

Comment: @Anthony: I just fiddled around in LINQpad and it seems the compile-time types of the arguments do in fact matter somehow. If I *declare* the array as `object` it fails with the above error, if I do it with `dynamic` it works. So, I was wrong. (I find the behaviour counterintuitive though, I expected the method resolution to be based entirely on the runtime types involved.)

Comment: @Inerdia, yes, that's the point. It matters because you declared it *dynamic*, you are telling the runtime to figure it out. In the question (and when you used `object`), no such declaration was made, so it didn't inspect `list` any further.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that `list` in the `GetTotal` method is not a `List<int>`.

The dynamic call is determined based on the type of the variable that you use, not the actual type of the object that it's pointing to. The method `Total` takes a `List<int>`, not an `IEnumerable`.

Comment: I was under the impression that a dynamic call would try to dynamically resolve the parameters as well as the method.  I guess not.  When I change the call to *return listTotaller.Total((dynamic)list).ToString()*, it works.

Comment: @afeygin: The dynamic code tries to figure out what `"Total"` is, and to find the right overload (eventhough you happen to have only one) it uses the types of what you use for parameters. If it used the actual types instead, it would call the wrong overload, i.e. calling `Total(List<int>)` even if there was an overload `Total(IEnumerable)`.

Answer (score 4):

It is because while calling the function Total, IEnumerable  cannot be converted to a type of List.

```
List implements  IList<T>, ICollection<T>, 
          IEnumerable<T>, IList, ICollection, IEnumerable
```

passing

```
IEnumerable<int>
```

to both **Total** and **GetTotal** would do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

it's the fact that you can't cast from `IEnumerable` to `List<int>`
Try it with this line instead

```
public float Total(IEnumerable<int> list) { return list.Sum(); }
```

so it's not your dynamic failing, it's the function call not passing in valid arguments

Comment: Though you've identified the issue, I don't think your solution will work. You'd be calling a method whose only parameter is `IEnumerable<int>` with an argument of compile-time type `IEnumerable`. Overload resolution will fail, since you can't implicitly convert `IEnumerable` to `IEnumerable<int>` (though you *can* go the other way.)

Comment: To be pedantic, `IEnumerable` (nor `IEnumerable<int>`) isn't a subtype of `List<int>`. (You can certainly *cast* between them, because casting in C# is a runtime operation that checks whether this is the case at runtime when it's not at compile-time.)

Answer (score 1):

That's an addition to Guffa's answer (which is still completely valid).

Like afeygin I thought that a dynamic call would check the right underlying type.
But in my situation I had no chance to modify the interface because of the lack of information.

Here's the example:

```
// I know that doit will be a certain type like MyDoIt but i can't know the actual type
// The only information I have is that MyDoIt is implementing IToBeDone 
public void DoIt(IToBeDone doit)
{
    // I know that _doItInstance.DoIt will expect MyDoIt but can't know the actual
    // type here so this will throw
    _doItInstance.DoIt(doit);
}
```

Here's a workaround:

```
public void DoIt(IToBeDone doit)
{
    // this will cause that IToBeDone won't be used for type resolution but the real
    // type instead (in my case MyDoIt)
    dynamic dynDoit = doit;
    _doItInstance.DoIt(dynDoit);
}
```